# Github: Bumping version number in file

Tags: git, github, version-control, pull-request

Let's say that two developers are working on separate PRs. And their respective PRs include the same file, which has a version number in it. Both developers intend to bump this version number as part of their PR. How can you ensure that the second person to merge their PR to develop, even if it is just one second after the first developer, bumps the version number relative to the first developer's version number? The merging of the PRs is done in GitHub.

The version is an open api specification number. There are actually several such documents in the repository. Note that there won't be a merge conflict in the PR that gets merged after the first PR since both developers will have bumped to the same version.

What I want:

1. First Commit by Dev 1: **1.123.0**
2. Second Commit by Dev 2: **1.124.0**

what actually happens:

1. First Commit by Dev 1: **1.123.0**
2. Second Commit by Dev 2: **1.123.0**

Comment: Can you offer some clarity on what these numbers are supposed to represent? Usually, individual commits won't have version numbers. Instead, these will be assigned to specific commits where a release manager decides that a certain version is good to release. I have some suggestions but would like to know more before I answer.

Comment: See if you can't set it up such that merging a PR on Github automatically bumps the version number instead of doing it manually if it is that important :)

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim Open api spec version. There are several such documents with their own version number.

Comment: Don't.  Version numbers should be derived from the vcs.  Always.  When version numbers are derived from the vcs instead of hard-coded into files, problems like this simply don't exist.

Comment: What you are currently describing really shouldn't be an issue, though.  There will be a merge conflict in the second PR that will need to be resolved.  Are you trying to avoid the merge conflict?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I agree there will be a merge conflict if they try to change the line to different numbers, but if they try to change it to the same number, there won't be. I'm guessing this is the problem if they don't know about each other's change.

Comment: @Baz If you need a monotonically rising version number for every change in the document. You should probably have the team work off a single branch and then disallow merges to that branch. Have them work on there and when there's a push, automate the incrementing of version numbers from a single source.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 5):

> Both developers intend to bump this version number as part of their PR.

They should not do that.
Only a GitHub workflow could [update the API version](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/versioning-an-api), when their PR are accepted and merged to main, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69343233/6309).

Something like:

```yaml
name: Auto Increment OpenAPI Version

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    types: [closed]

jobs:
  increment-version:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Increment OpenAPI Spec Version
        run: |
          # Script to increment version numbers in OpenAPI documents
          ./increment-openapi-version.sh
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          git commit -am "Automatically bump OpenAPI spec version"
          git push
```

You can try that with [GitHub Action "Increment Semantic Version"](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/increment-semantic-version)

```yaml
name: Auto Increment OpenAPI Version

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    types: [closed]

jobs:
  increment-version:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Determine Current Version
        id: get_version
        run: |
          # Add your logic here to determine the current version from your OpenAPI document
          # For example, using grep or another tool to extract the version from a file
          CURRENT_VERSION=$(cat path/to/your/version/file.txt)
          echo "::set-output name=CURRENT_VERSION::$CURRENT_VERSION"

      - name: Bump release version
        id: bump_version
        uses: christian-draeger/increment-semantic-version@1.1.0
        with:
          current-version: ${{ steps.get_version.outputs.CURRENT_VERSION }}
          version-fragment: 'feature' # Adjust this based on your versioning scheme

      - name: Update OpenAPI Document Version
        run: |
          # Add your script/command here to update the OpenAPI document with the new version
          NEW_VERSION=${{ steps.bump_version.outputs.next-version }}
          # Example: sed -i 's/oldversion/$NEW_VERSION/g' path/to/your/version/file.txt
          echo "Updated version to $NEW_VERSION"

      - name: Commit and Push the New Version
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          git add path/to/your/version/file.txt # Update to include the actual file you modified
          git commit -m "Automatically bump OpenAPI spec version to ${{ steps.bump_version.outputs.next-version }}"
          git push
```

Answer (score 0):

After the first operation, the corresponding PR is merged to proceed with the git pull based on the base branch.

This will allow you to receive changes from previous developers.

At this time, it seems important to manage the version manually or automatically by hardcoding.

It can be very inefficient if you manage it with hardcoding. Usually, if you use it automatically, you can use with the *git command*, or you can manage the version with an *automatic script*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually adjust the version numbers in the second pull request before merging it into the main branch.

1. Merge the first pull request from the first developer that increments the version to `1.123.0`.
2. Before merging the second pull request, rebase it onto the latest commit in the main branch. This will incorporate the changes from the first pull request.

```
git fetch origin
git checkout dev-2-branch
git rebase origin/main
```

During the rebase, you might need to resolve any conflicts that arise, including the conflicting version number.

3. After rebasing, manually change the version number in the second pull request to be 1.124.0. You can do this by amending the last commit.

```
git commit --amend
```

4. Update the version number in the commit message and save the changes.
5. Since you've amended the last commit, you'll need to force push the changes to the remote repository.

```
git push origin dev-2-branch --force
```

6. Keep in mind that force pushing can rewrite history. Be Careful!
7. Now, you can merge the second pull request into the main branch, and it will have the adjusted version number relative to the first pull request.

Now version numbers of the second developer's changes are relative to the first developer's changes.